# XSD Schema for DocuSIgn REST API

Tags: docusignapi

We are trying to integrate DocuSign RestAPI with one of our connector project.
Could you please provide us  XML schema(XSD) for complete DocuSign RestAPI XML format If readily avaialable?

Answer (score 0):

There is no XSD schema for REST API.  You can however go with SOAP and just use the WSDL file.